# open a folder using java program

Tags: java, file-permissions, permission-denied

I need to open a directory (explore folder)

```
String path="/home/hp/Documents";
```

I tried to open a directory through this,

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(path));
```

This works fine in windows but in ubuntu it says

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to show URI:file:/home/hp/Downloads/drawable/
```

And when i use,

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runTime.exec(path);
```

It says,

```
Cannot run program "/home/hp/Downloads": java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
```

Comment: Ubantu is not able to read the path through "/" charactor. You can use File.seperator for working in all environment.

Comment: no,it does uses "/" character.

Comment: Can you clarify: You've set `path` to "/home/hp/Documents", but the error is about "/home/hp/Downloads...".
Can you provide *all* of the relevant code... not just a few lines.

Comment: `/home/hp/Downloads` is a folder, not an executable. So you cannot run it thru Runtime. Runtime#exec expects an executable program.

Comment: Thanks For this.Can u tell me a way to open the Folder through my program

Comment: Sorry my friend but Path is always "/home/hp/Downloads".

Comment: Is your Ubuntu desktop using Gnome? KDE? Something else?  Desktop.getDesktop().open(directory) properly displays a file explorer window when I run it.

Comment: On my computer it works. I mean the `Desktop.open()` variant. Ubuntu 14.04, user in adm. Did you check permissions the executing user has towards the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Like kailash gaur said in the comments, using `File.separator` in place of `/` should make it work cross-platform.

Comment: path = "/home/hp/Downloads" so how should i use file separator in this

Comment: `path = File.separator+"home"+File.separator+"hp"+File.separator+"Downloads"`

Comment: It still doesn't work.It says,Cannot run program "/home/hp/Downloads": java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:488)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:612)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)